# Операциональное преобразование

Tags: алгоритм

Есть ли пример реализации операционального преобразования, желательно для XML-файлов? Если кто-то занимался его реализацией самостоятельно, то подскажите, какую лучше [модель](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#.D0.9C.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B8_.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BB.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8) выбрать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочего и(или) приемлимого кода я не нашел.

Из [топика](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043165/operational-transformation-library) в stackoverflow
более или менее работает [библиотека share.js](http://sharejs.org/) на node.js,
[google-mobwrite](https://code.google.com/p/google-mobwrite/).

Еще есть хорошая [библиотека](http://operational-transformation.github.com//ot-for-javascript.html) и [визуализация ее алгоритма](http://operational-transformation.github.com//visualization.html)
и статья на английском "[Understanding and Applying Operational Transformation](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/understanding-and-applying-operational-transformation)"